# error in case statement (ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s))

Tags: mysql, operands

I have a Table from that want to get records on the bases of gender and score like if the score is more than 70 than male data will display else female data for this i want to use case statement.
 mysql query is

```
select Parent_Id,Emp_Id,Emp_Gender,Emp_Score from EVENT_DETAIL where 
Emp_Score = (case when Emp_Score > '70' then (select * from EVENT_DETAIL 
where Emp_Gender = 'Male') else (select * from EVENT_DETAIL where 
Emp_Gender = 'Female') end);
```

but in this am getting error of operand should contain 1 column

Comment: A `CASE` expression has to return a single scalar value.  You are returning an entire _table_ (many rows, many columns).  Your query makes no sense.

Comment: You'r mixing CASE expression with CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
(select Parent_Id,Emp_Id,Emp_Gender,Emp_Score from EVENT_DETAIL where Emp_Score > 70 and Emp_Gender = 'Male')
union all
(select Parent_Id,Emp_Id,Emp_Gender,Emp_Score from EVENT_DETAIL where Emp_Score <= 70 and Emp_Gender = 'Female');
```

Comment: the query you are telling is already i have tried but i want to do only with case statement

Comment: new query i have made           select * from EVENT_DETAIL where Emp_Score IN (case when Emp_Score >= '70' then (select group_concat('''',Emp_Score,'''') as Emp_Score from EVENT_DETAIL where Emp_Gender = 'Male') else (select group_concat('''',Emp_Score,'''') as Emp_Score from EVENT_DETAIL where Emp_Gender = 'Female') end); now am getting empty set.